# Backbone.js: models not appearing

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, coffeescript

I want to display a simple list of languages.

```
class Language extends Backbone.Model

    defaults:
        id: 1
        language: 'N/A'

class LanguageList extends Backbone.Collection

    model: Language
    url: '/languages'

languages = new LanguageList

class LanguageListView extends Backbone.View

    el: $ '#here'

    initialize: ->
        _.bindAll @
        @render()

    render: ->
        languages.fetch()
        console.log languages.models

list_view = new LanguageListView
```

`languages.models` appears empty, although I checked that the request came in and languages were fetched. Am I missing something?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`fetch`](http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/#Collection-fetch) call is asynchronous:

> **fetch** `collection.fetch([options])`
>
> Fetch the default set of models for this collection from the server, resetting the collection when they arrive. The options hash takes `success` and `error` callbacks which will be passed `(collection, response)` as arguments. When the model data returns from the server, the collection will reset.

The result is that your `console.log languages.models` is getting called before the `languages.fetch()` call has gotten anything back from the server.

So your `render` should look more like this:

```
render: ->
    languages.fetch
        success: -> console.log languages.models
    @ # Render should always return @
```

That should get you something on the console.

It would make more sense to call `languages.fetch` in `initialize` and bind `@render` to the collection's `reset` event; then you could put things on the page when the collection is ready.

Also, `_.bindAll @` is rarely needed with CoffeeScript. You should create the relevant methods with [`=>`](http://coffeescript.org/#fat_arrow) instead.

Comment: doesn't reset empty the collection? I don't see how I could use it.

Comment: @alste: `reset` is also an event that a collection will trigger: http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/#FAQ-events